# Appending a form in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Im trying to append a `form_for` to a `div` with no luck, I've been through everything in the javascript console inside the div that holds the form but can't seem to find the contents to target. Please let me know if this is hard to understand and i'll try to explain myself better. I have also tried

```
$('.admin-right-content').innerHTML = "<%= render 'products/add_products' %>"

$(".admin-right-content").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @add_products) %>");

$(".admin-right-content").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => add_products) %>");

$(".admin-right-content").append("<%= escape_javascript(render add_products  %>");

$('.admin-right-content').append($('.add-products-form'))
```

The list goes on and on.

I'm a newbie to Rails, so apologies if this turns out to be something simple or some silly mistake on my end.

The partial containing the form is `_add_products.html.erb`.

Instead of printing the form out its actually appending the code to the div.

```
    <div class="add-products-form">
      <%= form_for @product do |form| %>
        <%= form.label 'Product name' %>
        <%= form.text_field :product_name %>
        <%= form.label 'Type'%>
        <%= form.text_field :type %>
        <%= form.label 'Price' %>
        <%= form.text_field :price %>
        <%= form.label 'Description' %>
        <%= form.text_area :description %>
        <%= form.label 'Add photos' %>
        <%= form.data_field :photos %>
        <%= form.submit "Submit" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Comment: `$('.admin-right-content').innerHTML` jQuery object do not have an `innerHTML` property. This line of code will be causing an error

Comment: Where are you writing this code? Is it a `.js` file or `.js.erb` file?

Comment: sorry, its a js file

Comment: which code it is printing ? js code or form code?  what do u mean by printing code?

Comment: it is printing this => "<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @add_products) %>"

Comment: @Dave rename your file .js to .js.erb.   Because you are including ruby code in it.

Comment: That makes sense... Thanks.

Comment: @krishnar is there a way to do it without adding erb?

Comment: @Dave can u show controller ?

Comment: @Dave If you want to include ruby code it must be .erb

Comment: @krishnar, so I could add a display: none to the div and then on click remove that attribute, would I be right in thinking thats a sloppy way of doing it?

Comment: @Dave reason behind not making it erb?

Comment: Theres a lot of articles saying its bad practice... So I just took there advice. Is it not as bad as they say then?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
$('.admin-right-content').append($('.add-products-form').children().clone())